# Is pronouncing "the" as "thee" to specify something a proper practice?

Tags: pronunciation

I am not a native speaker, when I was a child on of my friends use to pronounce "the" as "thee" all the time and the teacher kept telling her that you she should do that only if the word after "the" starts with a vowel. Like "Thee injection", "Thee orbit" other wise it's "The umbrella" and "The pen".

Years later I found out that English speakers specify or empathize by saying "Thee". Is this proper?

Comment: Are you comparing the two pronunciations of "the." 'The' that rhymes with 'bee' and 'the' that rhymes with 'duh'?

Comment: I would say "thee" umbrella but "thuh" pen - "uh" is a vowel sound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a speaker wants to emphasize nouns he can use the emphatic forms of the articles:

> Air, water, soil are ˈthe /ðiː/ problems of our century.
>   That's ˈthe /ðiː/ idea.

This emphatic *the* is pronounced with a long /i/, whereas the *the* before vowels is pronounced with short /i/:

> the egg /ði eg/

The indefinite article also has an emphatic form /eɪ/:

> ˈA /eɪ/ wonder!

Of course, that is a thing you can hear sometimes in public speeches. I would not use it as a non-native in normal language.

Answer (score 4):

According to Merriam-Webster, *the* is pronounced as:

> - before consonants usually **thə**
> - before vowels usually **thē**
> - sometime before vowels also **thə**
> - for emphasis before titles and names or to
>     suggest uniqueness often **ˈthē**

So yes, if the word following *the* starts with a consonant, it is normally pronounced as **thə** (like 'duh') and before vowels as **thē** (like 'see').
If you want to emphasize, you can also use **ˈthē**. Note that the ' before it signifies aspiration, which is not normally the case when pronouncing *the*. It may be a small difference, but it is one that can definitely be heard in speech and will make a difference in the hearer's interpretation.